# ESLint: Cannot override AirBnb Extent?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm using this .eslintrc setup generated by the `eslint --init` command.
It offers me to chose the airbnb styleguide which is a good start to me

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  rules: {
    "react/state-in-constructor": [0, "never"],
    "arrow-parens": 0
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    "react/state-in-constructor": [0, "never"],
    "arrow-parens": 0
  },
};
```

However, afterwards, it seems like it is enforcing some rules that i don't want for now which are :

```
rules: {
  "react/state-in-constructor": [0, "never"],
  "arrow-parens": 0
},
```

But it is not taken in account by VSCode or Eslint command.

Someone faced this issue ?

Best regards,
Louis